# Azure Server FHIR: Search Sorting

Tags: azure, sorting, hl7-fhir

I've been working on Azure FHIR,  however I could not find how to sort search results. I tried to follow the [HL7-FHIR documentation](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html), but it did not work.

```
GET [base]/Observation?_sort=status,-date,category
```

Anybody knows the correct way of sorting in Azure FHIR?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is not supported yet in the Azure API for FHIR. It is in our backlog, but no firm date yet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir-features-supported