# What is the default sort when searching for resources in Azure API for FHIR?

Tags: azure, sorting, hl7-fhir

Granted that `_sort` is not yet supported in Azure API for FHIR as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir-features-supported#search) and discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440906/azure-server-fhir-search-sorting) question, I'd like to know what the ***default*** sort is (assuming there is one).

For example, if I search for locations by making the following request:

```
GET [base]/Location?_count=10
```

The response contains `10` location resource entries as expected. The question is: **in what order are these resources?**

After doing some manual comparisons, the default sort *does not* appear to be on the following properties:

- `id`
- `name`
- `lastUpdated`

Is the default sort on some other field(s)? If so, which field(s)? Or is it that, in the absence of a `_sort` parameter, resources are returned in random or arbitrary order at the discretion of the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently only `_lastUpdated` is a supported sort param, and it's also the default sort for queries.

`GET [base]/Location?_count=10&sort=_lastUpdated` (well actually `&sort=_lastUpdated` is redundant because it's the default)

Or

`GET [base]/Location?_count=10&sort=-_lastUpdated` to sort descending.

Comment: I must have missed the ordering when manually comparing `lastUpdated` values; this does appear to be the default sort after some additional testing.